# Code of real word production apps that using Cordova, Ionic-Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Can anyone provide samples, links to repositories (github or smth) of real word apps that are in production
and using Cordova, Ionic-Framework?

For example wikipedia mobile app here: https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile, 
but it was updated long time ago. I am looking for fresh cases.

I now, that there is a lot of showcase and demo, but production apps have their own, code, project organization structure, build system organization, platform specific: html, sass, css tricks and it differ from demos which we are see at conferences and smth like.

Comment: what kind of specialties are you looking at ? The apps in showcase are not demos. They are apps that face public week in week out i.e. production app. Please be more specific :)

Comment: this is showcase, as you said, I am looking that inner of this - code, project organization structure, platform specialties, html markup and sass tricks for some platforms.

Comment: edited the answer to make it more specific to your question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But you know as for me,  code is the best doc ))

Comment: If I stumble upon some real world app, I will update my answer. I hope you are not expecting all your question to be answered by 1 app :)

Comment: I added 1 resource, will keep on adding more as I stumble on them :)

Comment: Edited my answer and added 5 code resources as well. Please make the answer as complete when you feel right :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I looked at repositories, and think it's too, simple to be the answer. I think about smth more complicated cases, like wikipedia app using PhoneGap https://github.com/wikimedia/WikipediaMobile

Comment: fancy marking the answer accepted ?

Answer (score 14):

This question is too general I think but luckily you have a official showcase from ionic team.

[Ionic apps showcase](http://showcase.ionicframework.com/)

But of course there are many more apps based on hybrid technologies, you may go through the following blog as well:

[Hybrid sweet spot: Native navigation, web content](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3743-hybrid-sweet-spot-native-navigation-web-content)

For code, you can start to google the apps up from the showcase. I think many of them are open source.

---

Edit based on the edits of the question :-
While it is hard to find out different production level code for the problem/ solutions you are looking for. I think a better approach it to seek experience in blog posts.

That way you will be made aware of the pitfalls of different platforms faster that looking into a production level code, if you find one.

A few good resources I came across my ionic journey is :-

1. [What I learned building an app with Ionic Framework](http://www.betsmartmedia.com/what-i-learned-building-an-app-with-ionic-framework)
2. [Top Tools and Resources for Hybrid App Development](http://www.noupe.com/design/top-tools-and-resources-for-hybrid-app-development-85714.html)
3. [Who uses cordova](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/03/27/who-uses-phonegapapache-cordova/)
4. [Fresh food finder blog](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/06/18/introducting-the-fresh-food-finder-an-open-source-phonegap-application/)
5. [Snapper for Digital Ocean Released](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/snapper-digital-ocean-released/)
6. [Admate for Chartboost Released](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/admate-for-chartboost-released/)
7. [Automate - BMW Hackathon App](https://www.behance.net/gallery/22787461/Automate-BMW-Hackathon)

Best code resources :

1. Hacker News- https://github.com/leonsas/hn-ionic
2. Fresh Food Finder - https://github.com/triceam/Fresh-Food-Finder (the best resource so far, that matches your requirements) - here is the supporting [blog](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/06/18/introducting-the-fresh-food-finder-an-open-source-phonegap-application/)
3. DropboxSync - https://github.com/ccoenraets/phonegap-dropbox-sync/tree/master/sample
4. Green Mahjong - https://github.com/danbeck/green-mahjong
5. Tweedie - https://github.com/aanon4/tweedie
6. ToDo Matrix - https://github.com/divyenduz/ToDo

Comment: Ping with any suggestions to https://twitter.com/divyenduz | I will gladly add them to the answer